# Best way to analyze and clean up permissions, profiles, and permission set?

Tags: permissions, profile, administration, permission-sets, cleanup

I’ve recently became an accidental Salesforce admin for a very large org and I’m working on scrubbing the profiles and permission sets since there seems to be a lot of irrelevant ones with minimal documentation.

What’s the best way to approach this and analyze what the current profiles and permission sets are doing?

Comment: Best discussed in the [Future of User Management Trailblazer Group](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F94S000000kKUlSAM) as otherwise this is opinion-based and hence likely to be closed